# Konami Key Sequence Array.splice() explanation needed

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, splice

I'm doing a [Konami Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Konami_Code) exercise in JavaScript and while I got it to work on my own, the answer makes no sense to me. Would someone care to explain?

My solution:

```js
const pressed = [];
var secretCode = 'wesbos';
window.addEventListener('keyup', e => {

  //My code   
  if (pressed.length < 6) {
    pressed.push(e.key)
  } else if (pressed.length === 6) {
    pressed.shift()
    pressed.push(e.key)
    console.log(pressed)
  }
  //End my code

  if (pressed.join('').toLowerCase() === secretCode) {
    console.log("SECRET COMMAND ACTION CODE TRIGGERED! COMMENCE KAMEHAMEHA");    
    $.getScript('http://www.cornify.com/js/cornify.js', function() {
      cornify_add();
      $(document).keydown(cornify_add);
    });
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

An answer from https://medium.com/@nikkoortega/key-sequence-detection-f90773e3aa60 which I don't understand:

```js
const pressed = [];
const secretCode = 'wesbos';
window.addEventListener('keyup', e => {
  
  //Answer code
  pressed.push(e.key)
  pressed.splice(-secretCode.length - 1, pressed.length - secretCode.length)
  //End answer code

  if (pressed.join('').toLowerCase() === secretCode) {
    console.log("SECRET COMMAND ACTION CODE TRIGGERED! COMMENCE KAMEHAMEHA");
  }
})
```

Comment: [Array.prototype.splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice?retiredLocale=id)

Comment: @ggorlen. hey thanks for your answer. it was so precise, it helped me a lot.  I rolled it back because the new edit didnt have the code i came up with as well as the answer code I was provided, which was confusing me.  the edit seem to give the necessary information for the question i was asking.  i didnt realize it had an issue being run in the snippet

Comment: No problem, just curious!

Answer (score 1):

The point of the code is to create a [queue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queue_(abstract_data_type)), a FIFO structure.

[`Array#splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) is a confusing in-place function that removes elements starting at the first parameter up to the second parameter, with negative indices wrapping. The third parameter optionally adds new elements but it's not used here.

In the solution, `-secretCode.length - 1` is basically a constant, -7 if the length of the secret code is 6. This is totally pointless and can just be replaced with 0 since they're really trying to access the first element, which is what should be dequeued.

The second parameter is `pressed.length - secretCode.length` which takes the difference between the number of keys collected so far and the total length of the secret code. This is `<= 0` up until the pressed queue exceeds the size of the secret code, at which point it's 1, meaning the first element is dequeued because the `splice` call will look like `splice(0, 1)`. When `splice` is called with a negative number like `splice(0, -1)` or `splice(0, 0)` it doesn't have any effect.

Here's a simplified and annotated version:

```js
const pressed = [];
var secretCode = 'wesbos';
window.addEventListener('keyup', e => {

  pressed.push(e.key);
  
  console.log(
    "after push, before splice", 
    pressed + "", 
    pressed.length - secretCode.length
  );

  pressed.splice(0, pressed.length - secretCode.length);
  
  console.log("after splice", pressed + "");
  console.log("______________");

  if (pressed.join('').toLowerCase() === secretCode) {
    console.log("SECRET COMMAND ACTION CODE TRIGGERED! COMMENCE KAMEHAMEHA");
  }
})
```

```html
<p>type: "wesbos"</p>
```

My opinion is that `splice` should usually be avoided, especially when messing with negative indices and adding elements. It's linear, clever, hard to understand and you're usually using the wrong data structure if you have to pop elements out of the middle of an array.

I prefer your approach but I'd write it like:

```js
const pressed = [];
var secretCode = 'wesbos';
window.addEventListener('keyup', e => {
  pressed.push(e.key);
  
  while (pressed.length > secretCode.length) {
    pressed.shift();
  }

  if (pressed.join('').toLowerCase() === secretCode) {
    console.log("SECRET COMMAND ACTION CODE TRIGGERED! COMMENCE KAMEHAMEHA");
  }
})
```

```html
<p>type: "wesbos"</p>
```

The `while` could be `if` since we know we're always adding 1 element, but it also doesn't really hurt to keep it `while` either -- the point is that it's enforcing dequeues until the queue is the same size as the target word.

One of the annoying things about JS is that it doesn't have a good builtin queue structure, so we have to `shift()` an array. This is still linear, but at least it communicates intent of implementing a queue more clearly than a `splice` that's always operating at index 0 and always removing no more than 1 element, in spite of negative indexing obfuscation.